# Que hace transform:translate (busco explicacion)

Tags: html, css

llevo un rato tratando de situar un botón en el centro de una imagen y finalmente en W3Schools he encontrado una solución, lo hacen con

```
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

el:

```
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
```

ya lo tenia, pero me quedaba el botón ligeramente desplazado, tras añadir eso he conseguido lo que buscaba, pero soy bastante novato en la programación y no se que son esos comando. Me gustaría saberlos para aprender de cara a un futuro esas funciones que me pueden ser útiles supongo.

Adjunto el código por si ayuda.

HTML

```
<div class="pagecontainer">

  <!-- SOCIAL -->
  <div class="fotoscategoriashomediv">
  <img class="fotoscategorias" src="secciones/comprimidas/Social.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="botonescategorias">
    <button type="button" name="Social">  <a class="enlaceblanco textoboton" href="social.html">Social</a></button>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS con el que funciona

```
 position: relative;
}
.fotoscategorias{
 width: 100vw;
}
.botonescategorias{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
button{
 background-color: transparent;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
button:hover{
box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.44), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
}
.textoboton{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
color: white;
font-size: 200%;
margin: 10px;
}
```

CSS con el que no funciona

```
  position: relative;
}
.fotoscategorias{
  width: 100vw;
}
.botonescategorias{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom:50%;
  right:50%;
}
button{
  background-color: transparent;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
button:hover{
box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.44), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
}
.textoboton{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
color: white;
font-size: 200%;
margin: 10px;
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Claro, pero no entiendo porque con esa funcion si consigo ponerlo en el centro y sin ella no. Si no no habria preguntado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola no es necesario agregar el `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` igual esa propiedad sirve para posicionar un elemento en el eje X y el eje Y. mira los cambios que hice del código CSS que dices que no funciona.

```
.botonescategorias{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 106px;
}
```

Espero te sirva de algo, solo darle un ancho al elemento y agregar el `margin` es mas que suficiente para centrar un elemento con `position: absolute;` saludos.